# Syntax error in ORDER BY in COLLECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, syntax-error, oracle19c

Why do I get a syntax error in the `order by` in this code:

The syntax error is reported by Oracle SQL Express and https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/

```sql
select cast(collect(
   case
      when (1 = 1) then 
         'aaa'
      else 'bbb'
   end
order by mt.my_col) as t_varchar2_tab)
from my_table mt;
```

[image]

Comment: have you declared t_varchar2_tab type?

Comment: Don't use Eversql for Oracle SQL. It doesn't support Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Just add one more `cast`:

```sql
select cast(collect(
   cast(
     case
        when (1 = 1) then 
           'aaa'
        else 'bbb'
     end
     as varchar2(100)
    )
order by mt.my_col) as t_varchar2_tab)
from my_table mt;
```

Full example:

```sql
with my_table as (select to_char(level,'000') my_col from dual connect by level<=10)
select cast(collect(
   cast(
     case
        when (1 = 1) then 
           'aaa'
        else 'bbb'
     end
     as varchar2(100)
    )
order by mt.my_col) as t_varchar2_tab)
 as res
from my_table mt;

RES
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
T_VARCHAR2_TAB('aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa')
```

PS. DOn't use eversql for Oracle SQL. It supports MySQL only

Comment: Sorry, your examples are still reported containing a syntax error on the `order by` by SQL Developer, the version I have here is  19.2.1.247.

Comment: What's your Oracle database version? `select * from v$version`

Comment: Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production.

Version of SQL Developer is 19.2.1.247.

Comment: show your full test case and error output.

Comment: Updated question with an image of the error.

Comment: Have you tried to execute it? Which ora- error does it return?

Comment: It doesn't give an error while executing, but SQL Developer says that there's a syntax error.

Comment: ok, so that's not a database problem, just SQL Developer. you need to create SR to Oracle support or at least create a topic about this on https://community.oracle.com/

Comment: @thatjeffsmith are you here? :)